# Is 'And you?' idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

Is **and you?** idiomatic in the following?

– How are you?
– I'm great, **and you?**

The usual question is **How / What about you?**
Does **and you?** sound natural?

Comment: It's certainly used.  More common in some circles than others.

Comment: Seems perfectly idiomatic to me (UK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language use changes according to context. In English, when you are in familiar or relaxed contexts the vocabulary and grammar often become more informal, and more informal sentence structures often results in less words being used to convey the meaning.

If words can be left out, but inferred from the context, then that often happens in informal settings. This is what is happening here. In the most familiar settings, sometimes words can be dispensed with entirely and a glance or raised eyebrow can communicate the same meaning.

The example you give sounds natural to me. I wouldn't call it "idiomatic" since it's not using words differently from their basic meaning in a way particular to English. It's just informal sentence structuring.

Comment: In this context *idiomatic* doesn't mean "using words differently from their basic meaning", it means "containing expressions that are natural and correct", that [seem natural to native speakers](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idiomatic).